# PyQt4 QVBoxLayout.addStretch() adds unwanted blank space when not needed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I'm having some trouble with PyQt4 isn't behaving quite as desired.

I have a search box, a list below and a optional picture to the right of the searchbox and list.

Without a stretching spacer, the items will get all the excess space divided between them.

The problem is that when I add a stretch item, it takes up more space than needed when there is nothing in the list, adding excess blank space in the window.

### This is a minimal example demonstrating the issue

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class SearchTool(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SearchTool, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.searchField = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        self.gui_0 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.gui_0.addWidget(self.searchField)

        # Comment out the following line to see desired output.
        self.gui_0.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(self.gui_0)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SearchTool()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**With .addStretch()**
[image: with stretch]

**Without .addStretch()**
[image: without stretch]
This is what I want it to look like.

### The reason for the stretch

**Just the list, no picture on this item.**
[image: List without picture and stretch]

**The list and the picture, without the stretch.**
[image: List with picture, without stretch]

**The list and the picture, with stretch.**
[image: List with picture, with stretch]
This is what I want it to look like.

Comment: Why can't you just add the spacer after all the other items have been added?

Comment: The items in the list are added and removed based on the contents of the search field. I could add logic around the updating of the list, adding and removing the spacer, but I would prefer finding a proper way of fixing the issue. Qt seems to think the window should be bigger than I want it. adding stretch=True to the addWidget for the search box gives a window with the same size.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, add the stretch after showing the window:

```
self.show()
self.gui_0.addStretch()
```

Comment: This unfortunatly only works untill a .adjustSize() is called on the main window. It works in the simple example, becouse no content is actually updated, but as soon as you start adding items (and they take up less space than the size the window seems to wish to be), the extra blank space reappear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the "correct" solution, but it would seem that you can just resize the height of the window to some small value, and the layout will then automatically re-expand to the minimum required height:

```
    self.setLayout(self.gui_0)
    self.adjustSize()
    self.resize(self.width(), 1)
    self.show()
```

But I still don't understand why the layout is initialised with a redundant spacer...